# Converting Date from String to oracle.jbo.domain.Date in java

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have a date in string format like this `2/14/2014`. I want to convert this date to `oracle.jbo.Date` Object in java. How can i do that?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont give the month as 2/14/2014. it should be 02/14/2014.

```
        if(inputDate!=null){
             try {
              DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
              date = formatter.parse(inputDate);
              java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
              oracle.jbo.domain.Date jboDate = new oracle.jbo.domain.Date(sqlDate);
                 System.out.println(jboDate);
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }

         }
```

You can try the same with SimpleDateFormat also.

Comment: I highly doubt 14 is the month.